# Able to serialize with boost but unable to deserialize std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

boost serialization

```
namespace boost { 

  namespace serialization {

    template <class Archive, class T>
    inline void save
        (Archive &archive, 
        const std::shared_ptr<T> subtree,  
        const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        // only the raw pointer has to be saved
        const T *const  subtree_x = subtree.get();

        archive << subtree_x;
    }

    template <class Archive, class T>
    inline void load
        (Archive &archive, 
        std::shared_ptr<T> subtree, 
        const unsigned int file_version)
    {

        T *p_subtree;

        archive >> p_subtree;

        #if BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_DINKUMWARE_STDLIB, == 1)
            subtree.release();
            subtree = std::shared_ptr< T >(p_subtree);
        #else
            subtree.reset(p_subtree);
        #endif
    }

    template <class Archive, class T>
    inline void serialize
        (Archive &archive, 
        std::shared_ptr<T> subtree,  // no const or else get compile-time error
        const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        boost::serialization::split_free(archive, subtree, file_version);
    }

  } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

tree class

```
class Tree{

private:

class TreeNode{

public:


    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> node_factory(const T &new_key, const long &new_index)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(new_key, new_index)); 
    }

    friend class Tree;

private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int /* file_version */){
        archive & key;
        archive & index;
        archive & left;
        archive & right;
    }

    T key;
    long index;

    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> left;
    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> right;

};  // End Tree Node Class Definition

friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int version){
    archive & root;
}
 };
```

writer

```
bool save(std::shared_ptr<Tree> &tree, const std::string &search_tree_file_name)
{
    // create and open a binary archive for output
    std::ofstream writer(search_tree_file_name, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

    if(writer){
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive serial_writer(writer);
        //set_flags(0, true);
        // write class instance to archive
        serial_writer << *tree;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called

    }else if(writer.fail()){
        writer.clear();
    }
    return true;
}
```

reader

```
enter code here bool load(std::shared_ptr<Tree> &tree, const std::string &search_tree_file_name)
{
    // create and open a binary archive for output
    std::ifstream reader(search_tree_file_name, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    if(reader){
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive serial_reader(reader);
        // read class state from archive
        serial_reader >> *tree;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called

    }else if(reader.fail()){
        reader.clear();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have written to and verified the successful serialization to a file but fail to deserialize from and into a usable object.

Whether I am writing in text or binary, I can verify the serialized output is correct but, for some reason, the serialize output does not deserialize and I am left with an empty object when loading.

Comment: I would recommend against defining the load/save for All shared pointers, but instead do it for `std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>`.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @n.m. Not getting errors.  Just don't see the deserialized data.  Once `serial_reader >> *tree;` has completed, tree is the same as it was passed in as an argument.

Comment: @DaveS I am also serializing the Tree `root` and hence why I am serializing the Tree as a `std::shared_ptr`.  Are you suggesting not serializing the `root` and simple serializing only the TreeNode?

Comment: This does not compile. Please post real code.

Comment: I don't think my suggestion is the source of your problem.  I'm suggesting that you NOT define save for all `std::shared_ptr<T>`, which defines it for all `std::shared_ptr`, such as `std::shared_ptr<int>`.  Instead, you should define it for `std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>`.

Comment: @DaveS I understand now.  You are referring to the boost::serialization namespace declarations.

Comment: Anyone have any clue regarding the reason I can serialize to but not deserialize from? using shared_ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these links, might provide you some clue.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/shared_ptr.html
& http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/shared_ptr2.html

Comment: I read through your links and made changes to the load, save, and serialize declarations but performed the following instead: Removed the namespace boost and serialization declarations and now utilize `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`. The serialization issues are now cured.

Answer (score 0):

Although `@Arun` provided great documentation references useful for utilizing `std::shared_ptr`, I instead chose to employ `boost::shared_ptr` with boost::serialization and it has cured my de-serialization problem.